# How do you make polygon made with pseudo elements responsive?

Tags: css

I have made a form that is inside of a polygone made with pseudo elements. I would like for the form to change size as the screen changes but can't figure out show to make my shape do that. I tired to change width of the form to 50% so the shape is 50% of the screen width at all times but that did not work for the psudeo elements

code pen: https://codepen.io/coolblow/pen/WyqjRx

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
header {
  height: 100px; 
  text-align:center;
  line-height: 100px;
  background-color: gold;
}
form {
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px #303030;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: -10px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 240px;
  position: relative;
}

form::before {
  content: '';
    width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent; 
  border-right: 20px solid transparent; 
  border-bottom: 20px solid lightgreen;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

form::after {
  content: '';
    width: 0; 
  height: 0;
  border-left: 120px solid transparent; 
  border-right: 120px solid transparent; 
  border-top: 70px solid lightgreen;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -70px;
  left: 0;
}

input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
header {
  height: 100px; 
  text-align:center;
  line-height: 100px;
  background-color: gold;
}
form {
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px #303030;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: -10px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 240px;
  position: relative;
}

form::before {
  content: '';
 width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent; 
  border-right: 20px solid transparent; 
  border-bottom: 20px solid lightgreen;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

form::after {
  content: '';
 width: 0; 
  height: 0;
  border-left: 120px solid transparent; 
  border-right: 120px solid transparent; 
  border-top: 70px solid lightgreen;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -70px;
  left: 0;
}

input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<form>
  <label for="lastname">Lastname: </label>
  <input type="text" id="lastname" />
  <br><br>
  <label for="firstname">Firstname: </label>
  <input type="text" id="firstname" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Didn't you ask similar questions some hours ago ?

Answer (score 0):

> You can use `transform: scale` for pseudo-elements. Just add below
>   media query in your stylesheet.

Here, I have changed size from `max-width: 360px`

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 360px){
  form {
    width:160px;
  }
  form::after {
    transform: scale(0.67);
    transform-origin: left top;
  }
}
```

Below is codepen. see it after scaling codepen width less than 360px.
https://codepen.io/vaishalik3/pen/MXMEBr?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, ::after and ::before elements are an inconvenient way to maintain a polygon.

If you wish it to be an html element such as div, this is what I suggest: use [clipping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) along with the [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) css function.

with no clipping - this will always be a rectangle (straight or rotated), it will never stretch / adopt well when changing the viewport.

If you desire some part to be unstretchy just use 'px' units in the appropriate coordinates.

example:

```css
    #my-polygon {
      min-height:100px;
    clip-path: polygon(0px 15%, 50% 0px, 100% 15%, 100% calc(100% - 20px), 50% 100%, 0px calc(100% - 20px));
    background-color:red;
    }
```

```html
<div id="my-polygon"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right direction with your pseudo element. But instead of using borders to simulate your polygon shape, you should use `clip-path`. You will find your code snippet below using it :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
header {
  height: 100px; 
  text-align:center;
  line-height: 100px;
  background-color: gold;
}
form {
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px #303030;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: -10px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

form::before {
  content: '';
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent; 
  border-right: 20px solid transparent; 
  border-bottom: 20px solid lightgreen;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

form::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color:lightgreen;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 50% 0px, 100% 0px, 100% calc(100% - 40px), 50% 100%, 0px calc(100% - 40px));
}

input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<form>
  <label for="lastname">Lastname: </label>
  <input type="text" id="lastname" />
  <br><br>
  <label for="firstname">Firstname: </label>
  <input type="text" id="firstname" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I only change one section in your CSS code (`form::after`). I used `position: absolute` to position the element at the complete bottom of your `form`. I gave it a size and the most important part is the clipping using `clip-path` to give it a triangle shape.

Hope it is useful to you!